# Flask App Javascript not working from localhost but works from 127.0.0.1

Tags: javascript, rest, post, heroku, flask

My application server: python+flask
UI: html + javascript with callback and POST method

Application runs fine with redirection, rest api call etc at:
http://127.0.0.1:5000/
When Submit button is clicked, nothing happens from:
http://localhost:5000/
Also nothing happens from:
http://finhelper.herokuapp.com/   <-- html + java scripts can be read here

I think none of the Javascripts are working for some reason when running without 127.0.0.1.
CSS and separate pages work though.

EDIT:

the below javascripts are taking me to: http://127.0.0.1:5000/approve
Which is same as:
http://finhelper.herokuapp.com/approve

This redirection is not working from Heroku.

```js
 <script type="text/javascript">

  function Submit(callback) {
   //url = 'http://finhelper.herokuapp.com/api';
   url = '/api';
   ItemJSON = '[  {"Married": 0,"Education": 0,"ApplicantIncome": 5000,"CoapplicantIncome": 1100,"LoanAmount": 150,"Credit_History": 1}]';
   //alert(url);
   var xhttp;
   var l_redir ='/';
   xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
   xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
     //alert('in this');
     myFunction(this);
     
    }
   };
   xhttp.open("POST", url, true);
   xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
   xhttp.send(ItemJSON);
   //alert('sent REST call');
   window.location.href = l_redir; //not being used
   return false;
  }
  function myFunction(xhttp) {       //Callback function
   //alert('in callback');
   retval = xhttp.responseText;
   //alert(retval);
   var redir = '-';
   
   if (retval.includes("approved")) {
    redir = "/approve";
   } else {
    redir = "/reject";
   }
   //alert(redir);
   redirect(redir);               //Final redirection depending upon ML Return value
  }
  function redirect(redir) {
   window.location.href = redir;
   return false;
  }
 </script>
```

2nd EDIT:
I can access this POST api that is running on same app.py from CURL but not from Javascript. Hence not getting httpResponse, identified using alert().
Any reason or suggestions please?

```js
curl http://finhelper.herokuapp.com/api -k -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "[{\"Married\": 0,\"Education\": 0,\"ApplicantIncome\": 5000,\"CoapplicantIncome\": 1100,\"LoanAmount\": 150,\"Credit_History\": 1}]"
```

Comment: Did you add `127.0.0.1 localhost` to your host file ?

Comment: yes, apart from localhost, the site is not working on Heroku also.

Comment: What do you mean with "not working" which part is not working ? I can access now (?)

Comment: thanks @AhmetZeybek , I edited the question with these details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added alert() at almost each step of the javascript. 
It turned out, on Heroku, python REST app was taking bit longer time and hence asynchronous ajax call was timing out.

For now I have added some delay but ideal way would be to implement below:
[Need a delay function javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4864471/need-a-delay-function-javascript#)

Answer (score 1):

Use **app.run(host= '0.0.0.0')** instead of **app.run()** only

Answer (score 0):

For people facing same issue after updating their mac to macOS Monterey, the new Airplay feature is listening to port 5000.

You can check that by typing

```sh
lsof -i:5000
```

to solve this issue, Control Center stops listening to those ports when “AirPlay Receiver” in the “Sharing” System Preference is turned off.

More details on the link below
https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/682332